# Subclass API Model Not work in tf.gradienttape() (No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext))

Tags: python, tensorflow

I Made tensorflow model by using subclass api and try to fit model by using gradient tape but in this process i got error like this when i execute this code :

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits_r,logits_cw = model(img,training=True)
    loss1 = balanced_entropy(logits_r,hr)
    loss2 = balanced_entropy(logits_cw,hb)
    w1,w2 = cross_two_tasks_weight(hr,hb)
    loss = w1*loss1+w2*loss2
```

No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)

how can i handle my error in this case

**This is model part of my code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import pdb
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'

#print('Is gpu available: ',tf.test.is_gpu_available());

#%%
def conv2d(dim,kernel_size=3,stride=1,rate=1,pad='same',act='relu'):
    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(dim,kernel_size,
            strides=stride,padding=pad,dilation_rate=rate))
    if act=='leaky':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    elif act=='relu':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

    return result


def dilation_conv2d(dim,kernel_size=3,stride=1,pad='same',act='relu',
    dilation_rate=1,use_bias=False):
    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(dim,kernel_size,
            strides=stride,padding=pad,use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate))
    if act=='leaky':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    elif act=='relu':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())    
    return result

def conv2d_2(dim,kernel_size=3,stride=1,rate=1,pad='same',act='relu',
    dilation_rate=1,use_bias=False):
    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(dim,kernel_size,
            strides=stride,padding=pad,use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
            dilation_rate=dilation_rate))
    if act=='leaky':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    elif act=='relu':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())    
    return result    

def max_pool2d(size=2,stride=2,pad='valid'):
    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=size,
            strides=stride,padding=pad))
    return result

def upconv2d(dim,size=4,stride=2,pad='same',act='relu'):
    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(dim,size,
            strides=stride,padding=pad))
    if act=='relu':
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    return result


class deepfloorplanModel(Model):
    def __init__(self,config=None):
        super(deepfloorplanModel,self).__init__()
        self._resnet50init()
        # room boundary prediction (rbp)
        self.rbpcv1 = conv2d_2(256)
        self.rbpcv2 = conv2d_2(256)
        self.rbpcv_final = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(3, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")

        # room type prediction (rtp)
        self.rtpcv1 = conv2d_2(256)
        self.rtpcv2 = conv2d_2(256)
        self.rtpcv_final = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(9, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding="same")
        
        # attention map
        self.atts1 = conv2d(dim=256)
        self.atts2 = conv2d(dim=256)
        self.atts3 = conv2d(dim=1,kernel_size=1,act='sigmoid') 
        # reduce the tensor depth
        self.xs1 = conv2d(dim=256)
        self.xs2 = conv2d(dim=1,kernel_size=1,act='linear')
        
        # context conv2d
        dak = [9,17,33,65] # kernel_shape=[h,v,inc,outc]
        # horizontal
        self.hs = self.constant_kernel((128,1,1,1))
        self.hf = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,[128,1],
            strides=1,padding='same',trainable=False,
            use_bias=False,weights=[self.hs]) 
        # vertical
        self.vs = self.constant_kernel((1,128,1,1)) 
        self.vf = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,[1,128],
            strides=1,padding='same',trainable=False,
            use_bias=False,weights=[self.vs]) 

        # diagonal
        self.ds = self.constant_kernel((128,128,1,1),diag=True) 
        self.df = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,128,
            strides=1,padding='same',trainable=False,
            use_bias=False,weights=[self.ds]) 
        # diagonal flip
        self.dfs = self.constant_kernel((128,128,1,1),diag=True,flip=True)
        self.dff = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1,128,
            strides=1,padding='same',trainable=False,
            use_bias=False,weights=[self.dfs])           

        # expand dim
        self.ed=conv2d(dim=256,kernel_size=1,act='linear') 
        # learn rich feature
        self.lrf=conv2d(dim=256)
        
        #dilated layer
        self.dilated_1 = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=1,use_bias=True)
        self.dilated_2 = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=1,dilation_rate=1)
        self.dilated_3 = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=3,dilation_rate=6)
        self.dilated_4 = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=3,dilation_rate=12)
        self.dilated_5 = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=3,dilation_rate=18)
        self.dilation_out = dilation_conv2d(256,kernel_size=1)
        self.dilation_sub = dilation_conv2d(48,kernel_size=1)

    def _resnet50init(self):
        self.base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False,
            input_shape=(512,512,3))
        for layer in self.base_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False    
        self.resnet50_a = Model(inputs=self.base_model.input, 
            outputs=self.base_model.get_layer('conv4_block6_2_relu').output)              
        self.resnet50_b = Model(inputs=self.base_model.input,
            outputs=self.base_model.get_layer('conv2_block3_2_relu').output)    


    def constant_kernel(self,shape,val=1,diag=False,flip=False):
        k = 0
        if not diag:
            k = val*np.ones(shape)
        else:
            w = np.eye(shape[0],shape[1])
            if flip:
                w = w.reshape((shape[0],shape[1],1))
                w = np.flip(w,1)
            k = w.reshape(shape)
        return k

    def DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(self, dspp_input):
        dims = dspp_input.shape
        x = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(dims[-3], dims[-2]))(dspp_input)
        x = self.dilated_1(x)
        out_pool = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(dims[-3] // x.shape[1], dims[-2] // x.shape[2]), interpolation="bilinear",)(x)

        out_1 = self.dilated_2(dspp_input)
        out_6 = self.dilated_3(dspp_input)
        out_12 = self.dilated_4(dspp_input)
        out_18 = self.dilated_5(dspp_input)

        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_pool, out_1, out_6, out_12, out_18])
        output = self.dilation_out(x)
        return output            
    # t1 : rbp /t2: rtp
    def non_local_context(self,t1,t2,stride=4):
        N,H,W,C = t1.shape.as_list()
        hs = H // stride if (H // stride) > 1 else (stride-1)
        vs = W // stride if (W // stride) > 1 else (stride-1)
        hs = hs if (hs%2!=0) else hs+1
        vs = hs if (vs%2!=0) else vs+1
        a = t1 
        x = t2
        a = self.atts1(a)
        a = self.atts2(a)
        a = self.atts3(a)
        a = tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(a)      
        x = self.xs1(x)
        x = self.xs2(x)
        x = a*x
        
        h = self.hf(x)
        v = self.vf(x)
        d = self.df(x)
        f = self.dff(x)
        c1 = a*(h+v+d+f)
        c1 = self.ed(c1)
        
        features = tf.concat([t2,c1],axis=3)
        out = self.lrf(features)
        return out
    def call(self, inputs):
        feature_a = self.resnet50_a.predict(inputs)
        feature_a = self.DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(feature_a)
        feature_a = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(512 // 4 // feature_a.shape[1], 512 // 4 // feature_a.shape[2]),
            interpolation="bilinear")(feature_a)

        feature_b = self.resnet50_b.predict(inputs)
        feature_b = self.dilation_sub(feature_b)

        common_feature = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([feature_a, feature_b])
        # room_boundary_Upsampling
        rbp_feature = self.rbpcv1(common_feature)
        rbp_feature = self.rbpcv2(rbp_feature)
        #128 x 128 x 256 feature
        attention_bp = rbp_feature
        rbp_feature = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(512 // rbp_feature.shape[1], 512 // rbp_feature.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(rbp_feature)
        rbp_feature = self.rbpcv_final(rbp_feature)
        #room_type_Upsampling
        rtp_feature = self.rtpcv1(common_feature)
        rtp_feature = self.rtpcv2(rtp_feature)
        rtp_feature = self.non_local_context(attention_bp,rtp_feature)
        rtp_feature = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(512 // rtp_feature.shape[1], 512 // rtp_feature.shape[2]),interpolation="bilinear",)(rtp_feature)
        rtp_feature = self.rtpcv_final(rtp_feature)


        return rtp_feature,rbp_feature
```

**and the error i got is like this**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    605           try:
--> 606             grad_fn = ops.get_gradient_function(op)
    607           except LookupError:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in get_gradient_function(op)
   2731     op_type = op.type
-> 2732   return gradient_registry.lookup(op_type)
   2733 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\registry.py in lookup(self, name)
     98     else:
---> 99       raise LookupError(
    100           "%s registry has no entry for: %s" % (self._name, name))

LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: IteratorGetNext

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LookupError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\HAN\OneDrive - UOS\바탕 화면\TF2DeepFloorplan-main - test_net\train.py in <module>
      111 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
----> 112     logits_r,logits_cw = model(img,training=True)
      113     loss1 = balanced_entropy(logits_r,hr)
      114     loss2 = balanced_entropy(logits_cw,hb)
      115     w1,w2 = cross_two_tasks_weight(hr,hb)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1035         with autocast_variable.enable_auto_cast_variables(
   1036             self._compute_dtype_object):
-> 1037           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
   1038 
   1039         if self._activity_regularizer:

c:\Users\HAN\OneDrive - UOS\바탕 화면\TF2DeepFloorplan-main - test_net\my_deepfloorplan_code.py in call(self, inputs)
    200         return out
    201     def call(self, inputs):
--> 202         feature_a = self.resnet50_a.predict(inputs)
    203         feature_a = self.DilatedSpatialPyramidPooling(feature_a)
    204         feature_a = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size=(512 // 4 // feature_a.shape[1], 512 // 4 // feature_a.shape[2]),

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1749           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1750             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1751             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
   1752             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1753               context.async_wait()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    922       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    923       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 924       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    925       if self._created_variables and not ALLOW_DYNAMIC_VARIABLE_CREATION:
    926         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3037       (graph_function,
   3038        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3039     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3040         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3041 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1967         possible_gradient_type,
   1968         executing_eagerly)
-> 1969     forward_function, args_with_tangents = forward_backward.forward()
   1970     if executing_eagerly:
   1971       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in forward(self)
   1492   def forward(self):
   1493     """Builds or retrieves a forward function for this call."""
-> 1494     forward_function = self._functions.forward(
   1495         self._inference_args, self._input_tangents)
   1496     return forward_function, self._inference_args + self._input_tangents

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in forward(self, inference_args, input_tangents)
   1224       (self._forward, self._forward_graph, self._backward,
   1225        self._forwardprop_output_indices, self._num_forwardprop_outputs) = (
-> 1226            self._forward_and_backward_functions(inference_args, input_tangents))
   1227     return self._forward
   1228 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _forward_and_backward_functions(self, inference_args, input_tangents)
   1375     """
   1376     outputs = self._func_graph.outputs[:self._num_inference_outputs]
-> 1377     return self._build_functions_for_outputs(
   1378         outputs, inference_args, input_tangents)
   1379 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _build_functions_for_outputs(self, outputs, inference_args, input_tangents)
    942         gradients_wrt_outputs.append(gradient_placeholder)
    943       with ops.device(None):
--> 944         gradients_wrt_inputs = gradients_util._GradientsHelper(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    945             trainable_outputs,
    946             self._func_graph.inputs,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tf_envs_0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_util.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients, unconnected_gradients, src_graph)
    632               grad_fn = func_call.python_grad_func
    633             else:
--> 634               raise LookupError(
    635                   "No gradient defined for operation '%s' (op type: %s)" %
    636                   (op.name, op.type))

LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass model can use model.fit, but you need to compile it before fit, and don't use gradienttape.
I believe there is a way to explicitly state fit procedure like using gradient tape. You should find an example for explicit compile and fit.